# How do I return a value from within a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class factorialdisplay {
  // Main Method. Prints out results of methods below.
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Asks user for input
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    int n = console.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
      System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial(n));
    }
  }

  public static int factorial (int n) {
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      f *= i;
      return f;
    }
  return f;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the output:

```
1! = 1 
2! = 2 
3! = 6 
4! = 24 
5! = 120
```

But when I run the code, I get this:

```
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 1
3! = 1
4! = 1
5! = 1
```

My question is, how would I return the result of each iteration of a `for` loop, through the `factorial` static method, to the `main` method?

Comment: Do you really want to return in this case?

Comment: A method returns exactly once.

Comment: Remove the `return` statement, from within the `for` loop. Just iterate from `2` to `n` and calculate `factorial` and once iterated, simply return `factorial` :-) Why to do the extra multiplication, anything multiplied by 1 is always the same value !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `return f;` statement which is there in the `for` loop. The return within the `if` will always return to the calling method immediately after the first iteration. And that is why you're getting 1 as the result for all the factorials.

```
public static int factorial (int n) {
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      f *= i;
      // return f; // Not needed - this is causing the problem
    }
    return f; // This is your required return
}
```

And as [Ravi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19347695/2024761) pointed out

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { // well 0 will return 1 as well, so no prob unless you don't need 0 factorial
  System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial(i)); // you need to pass i instead of n as i is the counter here
}
```

Comment: Congratulations on 10k +1 from me

Comment: @RaviThapliyal - I missed that out, but you caught it, so I was very much happy to give you the credit(you deserved it) and a +1 as well :)

Comment: @arynaq - Thank you for that. Feels really good to be able to reach this milestone!:)

Answer (score 1):

Don't return here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
  f *= i;
  return f; // here!
}
```

but rather at the end of your loop. You need to accumulate your final result over all iterations of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems with the code:

1. Start at `i = 1`
2. Call `factorial(i)` not `factorial(n)`

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { // (1) start at i = 1
     System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial(i)); // (2) pass i not n
   }
   ```
3. Return once; after the loop ends

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
     f *= i;
     // return f; // (3) don't return from here
   }
   return f;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... you sort of think of a `yield` operation (which is available in some languages, but **not** Java). `yield` is a construct which says: "return a value from the function, but bookmark the place where I currently am and let me come back to it later". `return` on the other hand says something like "return the value and discard everything I do". In Java, you can't "put a loop on hold" and come back to it later.

I undestand that what you are trying to achieve is not wasting time by repeating calculations (and just leaving the return which has been proposed in other answers **is incredibly bad for performance**; justr try it for some bigger numbers...). You could achieve it by not yielding the results, but storing them in an array. Like this:

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

```
// Asks user for input
System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
int n = console.nextInt();

int[] results = factorials(n);
for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
  System.out.println(i + "! = " + results[i]);
}
```

and the function:

```
public static int[] factorials (int n) {
  int[] results = new int[n + 1];
  results[0] = 1;

  int f = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    f *= i;
    results[i] = f;
  }
 return results;
```

}

Note that the above could be written better - I tried to modify your code as little as possible.